# Creating separate templates with ERB

Tags: ruby, erb

I need to be able to create distinct templates using ERB instead of having them all appended sequentially (assuming `.result` returns 0).

For example:

```
require 'erb'

ERB.new("<% FOO = 'foo' %>\n<% BAR = 'bar' %>").result
ERB.new("<% FOO = 'foo' %>\n<% BAR = 'bar' %>").result
```

Returns the following warnings:

```
(erb):1: warning: already initialized constant FOO
(erb):1: warning: previous definition of FOO was here
(erb):2: warning: already initialized constant BAR
(erb):2: warning: previous definition of BAR was here
```

proving that the second ERB is appending onto the first, or that some other shenanigans are occurring here. I have tried various routes with the bindings and `eout_var` to of no avail.

How do I get ruby to understand these are two distinct templates and not two parts of a whole?

---

Given the accepted answer, this would be the solution for my contrived example of the problem:

```
require 'erb'

class Foo
  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

class Bar
  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

ERB.new("<% FOO = 'foo' %>\n<% BAR = 'bar' %>").result(Foo.new.get_binding)
ERB.new("<% FOO = 'foo' %>\n<% BAR = 'bar' %>").result(Bar.new.get_binding)
```

Comment: Please show a *real* example of what you would use, not a broken demonstration.  That way, we can get down to helping you with your answer, not fixing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOO`/`BAR` constants live in ruby itself, not in templates, thus redefinition warning.

If you need different values for a constant then it's obviously not a constant. If values are the same - then there's no point in multiple definitions

Also look into passing a `binding` to `result`, by default it's a top level scope, but can be changed

Comment: I would not actually create templates with content like that. I was merely demonstrating proof of the issue I am observing.

Comment: @MattS. you can pass different binding (scope of execution) into `result`, default one is top level

Comment: That worked. I was just trying the default binding and that was not working for me. Now I created two dummy classes with `get_binding` and passed the binding as `Foo.new.get_binding` and `Bar.new.get_binding` and ruby is treating them as separate templates.

Comment: @MattS. Ruby was always "treating them as separate templates." A template, once compiled, is [just Ruby code that's called with `eval`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4f8245b70399d146305726ada8b58ecd74304cc8/lib/erb.rb#L891). Suppose you did this: `eval("FOO = 1"); eval("FOO = 2")`. The second `eval` would give you a warning because `FOO` is the same constant both times. That doesn't mean Ruby is "appending" one to the other; it just means you're evaluating them both in the same program, and that's what happens when you try to redefine a constant in a Ruby program.